# How do I hide Twitter Following/Likes?

Tags: twitter

A Twitter user's page usually shows **Tweets**, **Following**, **Followers**, **Likes**, and **Lists** at the top right below the banner image, as seen on [@shanselman's Twitter page](https://twitter.com/shanselman):
[image]

But it's apparently possible to hide everything but **Tweets** and **Followers**, as seen on 
[@IAmDeveloper's page](https://twitter.com/iamdevloper): [image: twitter page screenshot]

What Twitter setting accomplishes this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a setting. It's what happens when you don't use them.

If you didn't create any lists, Lists will not show.

If you don't favourite/like/heart any tweets, that Likes tab will not show on your profile either.